# Missing index reported in execution plan

Tags: sql-server, indexing

Query plans suggests a new index to be created, but it is very strange as that index exists. I have even deleted it and recreated with definition provided by execution plan.

Even more, that index is really used by the query plan...

Any idea what could be the cause?[image]

Comment: Please provide the SQL query.

Comment: @vaibhav: see picture

Comment: Can you please post missing index definition. I suspect its showing missing index for Included column which is not visible on screenshot. This is because, I see keylookUp in your execution plan.